# Graph Theory Question regarding Isomorphism and Matrix Transposes

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, matrix-calculus, graph-isomorphism

How would one prove true or false the statement "for an I, incidence matrix of a graph G, and a J, incidence matrix of a graph H, it is impossible for G and H to be isomorphic AND for the product of I with its transpose and J with its transpose to be equal?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4028558/edit) your question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: As a hint, consider $G=H$.

Comment: @Joffan that would prove it false because a graph can be isomorphic to itself, right?